# bulk generate wp taxonomy tags from wp title with self php script

Tags: customization

I want to generate wp title into tags using plugins, https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-full-auto-tags-manager/,
because I have millions of posts, the schedule / cronjob is not working properly.
so I want to execute manually with self php script, can I use a piece of code from the plugin and run it on ssh terminal independently, this is a piece of code:

```
$nsw_sql_gen_tags = $wpdb - > prepare(" SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = %s AND post_type = %s ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT %d ", 'publish', 'post', $nsw_limit);
/************************************************************************/
$nsw_query_gen_tags = $wpdb - > query($nsw_sql_gen_tags);
if ($nsw_total_posts >= $nsw_limit) {
    foreach($wpdb - > get_results($nsw_sql_gen_tags) as $key => $row) {
        $post_ID = $row - > ID;
        $post_title = $row - > post_title;
        $nsw_post_title = strtolower($post_title);
        $posttags = get_the_tags($post_ID);
        if ($posttags) {
            foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                //tags are available();
            }
        } else {
            $string = $nsw_post_title;
            require(dirname(__file__).
                '/cleanup_string.php');
            $keywords = explode(' ', $string);
            $nsw_i = 0;
            foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
                if ((preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]/", $keyword)) && (strlen($keyword) > 4)) {
                    nsw_get_keyword_console($keyword);
                    nsw_get_total_tags_console($nsw_total_tag);
                    $final_tags = ''.$keyword.
                    '';
                    $nsw_i++;
                    if ($nsw_i == 7) break;
                    wp_set_post_tags($post_ID, $final_tags, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

what is the fastest way to do it?
my main purpose is actually to create post relationship based on tags,
or to create related post 
(because I use the toolset view plugin, it only has a relationship based on tags feature, but does not have the feature to filter based on related post)

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach here would be to use a custom WP_CLI command to handle this. Have a read here for details - https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/commands-cookbook/

Comment: it seems the hook is very limited, I will learn it.